# Cannot serialise to XML in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm very confused at the moment with a basic ASP.NET Core 2 API project and content negotiation and returning something other than JSON.

I've had this working before in a 1.1 project but not in a 2. I basically want to return something either as JSON or XML depending on request type.

As part of that requirement I set up the XML formatter like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
    }
```

I could also use `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` but same difference (and tried). This is the way I've seen in countless examples and done before.

I have a single controller and single action, basically looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            success = true
        });
    }
}
```

Now when I run I get this back in Postman:

```
{"success": true}
```

So it works (or at least defaults) to JSON.

Then if I request using the header `Accept: application/xml` instead I now get a HTTP error of 406.

If I take off `options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;`, it will return JSON regardless.

What am I missing? I'm sat scratching my head on this. As far as I know I've registered an acceptable content formatter.

Comment: What happens if you use `options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter()` instead?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Same difference, I'd actually tried that too.

Comment: Do you get any relevant output in the Output > Debug window?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ahh yes I do as it happens - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor:Warning: No output formatter was found for content type '' to write the response.`.

Comment: Just wondering, can you really serialize anonymous types to XML?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeh I was just thinking along the same lines :P Hold on trying...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yep that was it! Switched to a concrete type and it suddenly seems a lot happier.

Comment: That's what happens when you go to the old XML, haha. Should I post an answer?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeh might as well just in case anyone else runs into it. Yeh per-say I always do JSON but gotta support XML for legacy reasons :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that anonymous types cannot be serialized into XML, so the formatter fails and falls back to the JSON formatter.

Solution: use classes when you need to return XML.

Comment: And be sure to have a parameterless constructor!

Answer (score 1):

[There is already open issue for that](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6438).

As a workaround try adding this option to Mvc:

```
options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", "text/xml");
```

with [FormatFilter] attribute

Answer (score 0):

As @So used to be good said, anonymous types can't be serialized into XML. Here is my example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProducesResponseFormatController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        // this worked well
        return Ok(new Model.appsettings.TokenSettings()); 

        // this didn't
        return Ok(new { A = new { B = "b inside a", C = "C inside A" }, D = "E" }); 
    }
}
```